# Usage of NAN in php

Tags: php, math, nan

I am currently working on writing a small math related library in php. I know there exists some kind of an analogue of javascript's `NaN` in php, it is a constant `NAN` of `float` type.

So far I have not ever come across this constant apart from php standard functions like `asin()` and alike, which will return this `NAN` value if you pass them an invalid parameter (>1 in this exact case).
This value is not detected by `is_float()` and `is_numeric()` since it is of `float` type, both of these functions return `true` and the only way to check it is `is_nan()`. Also, casting it to `(int)` will result in `0`;

```
$x = asin(3);   // $x = NAN
is_float($x);   // true
is_numeric($x); // true
$d = (int)$x    // $d = 0;

is_nan(0.5)     // false
is_nan($x)      // true
```

But none of existing libs whereof I know uses this behaviour, instead throwing an error is a common choice, as it seems.

So my questions are: which approach ought I to choose? why nowhere, apart from standard php functions, the `NAN` is used?

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking. I think it is sensible for a library to throw an error when attempting to work with numbers and something that isn't a number arises. I wouldn't say that NAN has *a use* other than to identify an issue, hence an exception.

Comment: @AndyG so why `asin` does not throw an error for instance?

Comment: It's just my speculation, but maybe it's because php feature to throw and catch was implemented later than the asin function?

Comment: In my opinion the math functions are essentially intended to be global functions (mathematical extensions) that we can use, they are not part of a framework (an object library), so their behaviour is basic. They will either, generally, return a value or NAN. A larger framework which uses the functions could wrap NAN in an exception.

Comment: the lack of proper documentation is upsetting